# Passing a grails select value from view to controller?

Tags: grails, select, controller

I have a grails select and the user selects one of the values which I want to pass to my controller. However when i try the following code I keep getting null

```
    <g:form name="myForm" action="myaction">
    <label>Select Table</label>
    <g:select id="mySelect" name="availabilityChoice" from="${['Table 1', 'Table 2']}" value=""/>
    <g:actionSubmit type="button" value="Update Availability" onclick="myselect.value" action="myaction" id="test"/>
```

Comment: You've shown how you're sending the data from the form but not the code that receives the value in the controller.

Comment: I did params.mySelect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your comment, you say that the controller is doing `params.mySelect` - this will not work.  It is the *name* of a form field that corresponds to the `params` key, not the *id*, so you need to use

```
params.availabilityChoice
```

instead.